# Curl "write out" value of specific header

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I am currently writing a bash script and I'm using curl. What I want to do is get one specific header of a response.

Basically I want this command to work:

```
curl -I -w "%{etag}" "server/some/resource"
```

Unfortunately it seems as if the -w, --write-out option only has a set of variables it supports and can not print any header that is part of the response. Do I need to parse the curl output myself to get the ETag value or is there a way to make curl print the value of a specific header?

Obviously something like

```
curl -sSI "server/some/resource" | grep 'ETag:' | sed -r 's/.*"(.*)".*/\1/'
```

does the trick, but it would be nicer to have curl filter the header.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The variables specified for "-w" are not directly connected to the http header.
So it looks like you have to "parse" them on your own:

```
curl -I "server/some/resource" | grep -Fi etag | sed -r 's/.*"(.*)".*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 26):

You can print a specific header with a single sed or awk command, but HTTP headers use CRLF line endings.

```
curl -sI stackoverflow.com | tr -d '\r' | sed -En 's/^Content-Type: (.*)/\1/p'
```

With awk you can add `FS=": "` if the values contain spaces:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=": "}/^Content-Type/{print $2}'
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Praytic make sure the response actually contains the header. The sed example didn't actually have the "Content-Type" header so the output was empty, but it works when checking another included header

Answer (score 13):

New in v7.83.0

```
curl -I -s -o /dev/null -w '%header{etag}' https://example.com/
```

Ref:
https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2022/03/24/easier-header-picking-with-curl/

- `-I` = download header only.
- `-s` = silent.
- `-o /dev/null` = redirect output to file, null means output it to nothing.
- `-w` = write out the header param to stdout.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers use the `-I` option and parse the output. It's worth noting that `-I` changes the HTTP method to `HEAD`. (The long opt version of `-I` is `--head`). Depending on the field you're after and the behaviour of the web server, this may be a distinction without a difference. Headers like `Content-Length` may be different between `HEAD` and `GET`. Use the `-X` option to force the desired HTTP method and still only see the headers as the response.

```
curl -sI http://ifconfig.co/json | awk -v FS=": " '/^Content-Length/{print $2}'
18

curl -X GET -sI http://ifconfig.co/json | awk -v FS=": " '/^Content-Length/{print $2}'
302
```

Comment: Please note, that on this case `$2` will contain `\r` character, what may cause an unexpected behavior. It could be fixed, however with setting record separator as this: `'BEGIN{RS="\r\n";} /^Content-Length/{print $2}'`

Answer (score -2):

curl -sSI "server/some/resource" | jq | grep 'ETag:'

you pass the JSON from curl to a beautifier such as jq, the output ends up looking better and grep filter runs better.

Comment: The question is about extracting headers from the response, not data from a JSON payload. (Also, surely the `jq` tool could extract the field you want, without the need to separately run `grep`.)

Comment: Unfortunately this answer does not solve the question